# Show that $\mathcal{C}(A)$ is the smallest convex of $E$ containing $A$.

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

> Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and $A$ a nonempty subset of $E$.
>
> Show that $$\mathcal{C}(A) = \biggl\{\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \lambda_kx_k \biggm| n \in \mathbb{N}^*, (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in A^n, (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) \in \mathbb{R}_+^n \text{ and } \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \lambda_k = 1\biggr\}$$  is the smallest convex of $E$ containing $A$.

My attempt ;

1) $\mathcal{C}(A)$ is convex: Clear using $\phi(t) = xt+(1-t)y$ and writing $x,y$ as defined.

2) It contains $A$: Just take $n=1$

For the smallest case I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: prove that, if $B$ is a convex set in $E$, $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in B$, $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n=1$, then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kx_k\in B
$$
(induction on $n$).

Comment: This is what I thought, but for the 'heredity' are there no subtlety ? It does not seem obvious (for me).

Comment: @Yass Once you prove the assertion, you have that every convex set containing $A$ must also contain $\mathcal{C}(A)$.

Comment: Oh you are right(+1). Thanks!